# jQuery click not working multiple times for changing the same div

Tags: jquery

I have one item (#engaged) to which I have to add a class on jQuery click. There are 20 variants on which if users clicks a different class will be added to #engaged.

For example, if the user clicks #one, class .one should be added to #engaged. Similarly, if the user clicks #two, class .two should be added to #engaged.

I know how to do it, but the problem is that it only works one or two times on page load. More clicks are not accepted, even if I remove the previous added class on next click. How can I make it accept more clicks without reloading the page?

```
$("#one").click(function () {
    $("#engaged").mouseenter(function () {
        $(this).addClass("one");
    });
    $("#engaged").mouseleave(function () {
        $(this).removeClass("one");
    });
});

$("#two").click(function () {
    $("#engaged").mouseenter(function () {
        $(this).addClass("two");
    });
    $("#engaged").mouseleave(function () {
        $(this).removeClass("two");
    });
});
```

..... and so on

Comment: Share your code please. :-)

Comment: Thanks a lot i have got my answer from @L_7337

Comment: Please do see my answer for how you can avoid creating an absurdly repetitious list of functions for your 20 elements. One is enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using the  `.click` event, it will not work on dynamically created elements:

```
$(‘.selector’).click(function () {
```

Try using `.on('click')` instead:

```
$(‘selector’).on('click', '.selector', function () {
```

Reference: [In jQuery, how to attach events to dynamic html elements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1359018/in-jquery-how-to-attach-events-to-dynamic-html-elements)

Reference 2: [Difference between .on('click') vs .click()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9122078/difference-between-onclick-vs-click)

Comment: @isherwood I do not understand what you mean in your edit, "(which you certainly should)"

Comment: My apologies. I edited the wrong answer in my haste. Undoing.

Comment: I see that this answer was selected, though I have no idea why. There's nothing about dynamically-created elements in the question.

Comment: @L_7337 well, there is still some problem after 5 or 6 clicks, please try to select different items in this page and you will come to know that still problem exists. http://topgravity.com/engaged-social-menu/

Comment: Everything seems to work indefinitely for me. Please clarify what element(s) the problem occurs on, or ask a new question.

Answer (score 0):

I'll take a crack at it, assuming you have a common class on your click targets (which you certainly should).

```
$('.myCommonClass').click(function() {
    var myStr = $(this).attr('id').replace('#', '');

    $('#engaged').attr('class', '').addClass(myStr);
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/zeNVW/

Comment: thanks for giving me some time. Your answer works perfectly as i checked in jsfiddle. But the problem is that its too heavy for me to grasp. I am new to jquery, still problem exists is the correct marked answer of L_7337, please check my comment there.